# Weird ReferenceError in Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following code in a .tsx file:

```
let hasReleased = false;
const firstTimeCbs: (() => void)[] = [];
export function onScreenLockReleasedFirstTime(cb: () => void) {
  if (!hasReleased) firstTimeCbs.push(cb);
  else cb();
}
```

I don't know why, when calling the method onScreenLockReleasedFirstTime from another module:

```
import { onScreenLockReleasedFirstTime } from '../components/common/dialogs/ScreenLock';
onScreenLockReleasedFirstTime(() => this.init());
```

I get the following error, even when the let declaration is initialized inline:

> ScreenLock.tsx Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access
> 'hasReleased' before initialization
> at onScreenLockReleasedFirstTime (ScreenLock.tsx)

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: did it say what line the error is coming from?

Comment: Yep, from the line inside the function where i ask if(!hasReleased)